# android back button not working

Tags: android, lua, cocos2d-x

these codes work well on Win32, but nothing happens on Android, any help would be greatly appreciate.

```
local function onKeyPressed(keycode, event)
        print("key pressed")
        if(keycode == cc.KeyCode.KEY_ESCAPE) then
            cc.Director:getInstance():endToLua()
        end
end

local listener = cc.EventListenerKeyboard:create()
listener:registerScriptHandler(onKeyPressed, cc.Handler.EVENT_KEYBOARD_PRESSED)
scene:getEventDispatcher():addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, scene)
```

Answer (score 0):

--    Back button in android

```
local function onKeyReleased(keyCode, event)
    if keyCode == cc.KeyCode.KEY_ESCAPE then
        cc.Director:getInstance():endToLua()
    end
end

local listener = cc.EventListenerKeyboard:create()
listener:registerScriptHandler(onKeyReleased,cc.Handler.EVENT_KEYBOARD_RELEASED)

local eventDispatcher = self:getEventDispatcher()
eventDispatcher:addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, scene)
```